# Wrong image on like button

Tags: image, facebook-like

To start with I am new to facebook "like" button integration

I have a facebook like button on my webside (http://www.mini-signs.dk/index.html), but the image showing when like button is pressed is incorrect. I've tried to use meta tag

in between  and  on the page but it seems like it choosing a images name Galleri-Andet-Normal.jpg in the same folder.

I've tried to delete the image and overwrite it, and now something different is showing in the facebook timeline when liking the side, but the image in the like button dialog is still wrong. If i put the content value in a browser the correct image is showing

I've tried a lot of things og googled to solve it my self

Please help me out.

Comment: Not sure I've seen it and it looks fine if you ask me

Answer (score 0):

Only option you have is that you `change your meta tags and WAIT`. Once your page is crawled again, you will get new images :)

Answer (score 0):

Try here and look where is the problem,

```
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mini-signs.dk%2Findex.html
```

> All the images referenced by og:image should be at least 200px in both
>   dimensions. Please check all the images with tag og:image in the given
>   url and ensure that it meets the recommended specification.
>
> fb:admins and fb:app_id tags are missing.